# Possible bug in latest google chrome (v62)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, ffmpeg

The following demo was working perfectly:

http://jsfiddle.net/r6wz0nz6/2/

The following is a sample of 'video-preview' class in action:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1uyQZNg2vE" 
target="_blank" class="video-preview" data-frames="100" 
data-source="http://i.imgur.com/BX0pV4J.jpg">
</a>
```

Now, if you use your mouse to scroll from left-to-right, somehow it is not working (shows thumbnail instead of current image position). This **was working perfectly** before v62. While, from right-to-left, it **works normally**.

**Updated** Please watch how this looks here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvDP-YXJgOk

Question: How can I overcome this bug/issue ?

P.S. the demo is based on this blog post (https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/how-to-generate-video-previews-with-ffmpeg/138)

**Update 2** 
Interesting, in the following part:

```
elm.mousemove(function(e) {
var left = e.clientX - elm.position().left;
slider.show().css('left', left -1); // <<---------------------- this line
img.css('left', -Math.floor((left / width) * frames) * width);
```

if I remove the '-1' like so:
`slider.show().css('left', left);`
It works from Left-To-Right, but now from Right-To-Left is showing same bug !!

**Proposed Workaround by @A. Wollf**
Change the "mouseout" to "mouseleave" and it seems to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/r6wz0nz6/388

Comment: It's not working particularly well in Firefox.

Comment: Running chrome v62 (osx), cannot replicate. Seems to be working fine

Comment: It was working on Chrome v61 and below and on works on current Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Also working fine for me using Chrome v62 in OSX and windows

Comment: @evolutionxbox I can replicate issue on chrome 62 32bits windows7. It looks like because of mouseout event being fired for no reason. EDIT: `mouseleave` seems to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/r6wz0nz6/388/

Comment: If you move the mouse from left to right *slowly* it keeps going back to the same thumbnail.  This may have worked in previous versions of Chrome but that doesn't make it a Chrome bug.

Comment: Please see this bug in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvDP-YXJgOk

Comment: @Archer ... if it worked in previous versions of Chrome and in current version it is not ... what can we call this ?

Comment: I just put a console.log in there to see what value it's trying to set to `left`, and it's going over 20,000 which is waaaay more than the image size.  It looks like some dodgy maths to me.

Comment: @Archer .... perhaps its Math, but unless some magic changed the calculations and code ... it looks like a bug to Me

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer It's more likely a change that's highlighted an existing bug that was previously not noticeable.  Just have a look at the calculations and see if you can see anything wrong in there.

Comment: Okay - I commented out 1 line and it looks fine now.  In the `mousemove` handler, comment out the line that starts `slider.show()`

Comment: @Archer mmm that really did solve it ... thanks for tip. 
Strange, any thoughts why this didn't show up in earlier chrome versions ?!

Comment: By the way , the "slider" is just a div sliding on top of the image. So I highly see a bug here... anyway thanks for the work around

Comment: Interesting, If I remove the '-1' like so:
               slider.show().css('left', left); 
It works from Left-To-Right, but now from Right-To-Left is showing same bug !!

Comment: Honestly, I didn't spend enough time on it to figure out the "why" of that element.  It just looks out of place and it works without it.  That's where the bug is, clearly.  Why it wasn't apparent before - who knows?

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks ... yes this solves it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159470/discussion-between-jalal-el-shaer-and-archer).